# Cobalt http cache not working always http request sent instead using the cache

Tags: browser-cache, cobalt

Environment :
Cobalt : cobalt 25.master.0
OS: ubuntu.

Scenario:
From cobalt trying to load url "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3" via simple html.
Every time reload the above url [ by using F5], http request is sent out side instead of using the values from cache.
Especially cache info related to response set with "Cache-Control max-age=43200", "Pragma: no-cache", "Expires: -1".

Same script used in firefox, there is no repeated http request sent, when page is refreshed/reloaded.

Tried cobalt with parameters to enforce cache like "cobalt --enable-server-cache --enable-client-cache -enable_tracing --cache-control "max-age=3600, public" --url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/cobalt/demos/content/demo-jsonplc/index.html" still observing same.

Any other things to be set in cobalt, so that http cache works fine as other browser
out/linux-x64x11_debug/cobalt --enable-server-cache --enable-client-cache -enable_tracing --cache-control "max-age=3600, public" --url=http://127.0.0.1:8000/cobalt/demos/content/demo-jsonplc/index.html